# Windows 11 screen lock breaks Logitech mouse wheel

Tags: windows-11, logitech-mouse, wireless-mouse, scroll-wheel

I have a Logitech MK295 keyboard and mouse. Actually I have tried 2 brand new ones out of the box. Whenever Windows 11 goes to a lock screen and is eventually released by pin or password, the scroll button on the mouse stops working. The only fix is to reboot.

I have tried adding another wired mouse and it doesn't work either, the scroll wheel that is. That points to the OS being the underlying cause. I can't seem to find anything online mentioning a similar issue anywhere.

The drivers are built in. I checked Logitech's site, and there are no drivers to download. It's really annoying and I am pretty much ready to just wipe the whole machine and start all over.

It's Surface Pro 15" about 2 years old connected to a Surface Dock and two monitors. I have tried the USB adapter in the dock and directly on the Surface, same results. I have updated the OS with all recent updates and I have checked all the mouse and scroll settings.

Any ideas or am I spending the next few days rebuilding?

Comment: I have a LogiTech K540 keyboard/mouse combination on a Windows 11 Pro desktop machine. The mouse wheel does not lock up. Are you able to try a different model of mouse on your Surface Pro machine to see if that helps?

Comment: I did, same result.

Comment: There must be some compatibility issue with the Surface Pro.  Otherwise, I am not sure.

Comment: I should add that I run this on another Surface through a Surface Dock as well, Windows 11 and it never shows this behavior. That's why I feel like something is FUBAR on this particular machine.

Comment: That is almost impossible to debug.

Comment: I agree. There is likely something at the hardware layer being affected by the lock and other is no way to untrigger it since I don't know what to try and trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suspected, and after some responses, I decided to image my computer using Macrium's imaging tool, so I had a backup, and then I ran a Windows 11 system reset. I chose to keep my data, and it took about 20 minutes to complete. Once I was able to log back in and create a profile, I tested the scroll wheel, and it worked. I tested Windows lock a few times throughout the day, and the scrolling worked afterward. I do wonder if I should have tried a new profile instead of resetting, but that ship has sailed. I hope this can help someone else in the future. Thanks for the responses.